# Definition of subgraph

Tags: graph-theory

From Rosen's Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications, 3ed, chapter 10 p. 663:
[image: subgraph]

> ...the edge set F contains an edge in E...

Which edge is the one of interest?

> ...if and only if both endpoints of this edge are in W.

Why `if and only if` is used here?  Can't they replace it with `whose endpoints...`?  Please help.  The English used here is hurting my head.

Comment: An example of an edge which intentionally *isn't* kept in your pictured example would be the edge between $a$ and $d$.  That because if we *were* to include the edge it would effectively have one endpoint at $a$ and the other endpoint would be non-existent since $d$ is not in the vertex set of our subgraph that we are discussing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which edge is the one of interest?

All of them. Definition 8 says that for every single edge, the two statements "This edge is in $F$" and "This edge has both its endpoints in $W$" are equivalent statements (that's what "if and only if" is there for). In other words, for every single edge, those two statements are either both true or they are both false.

> Can't they replace it with `whose endpoints...`?

No. The statement

> The edge set $F$ contains an edge $E$ whose endpoints are in $W$.

is not the correct definition of an induced subgraph. This doesn't say that *every single edge* comes under the scrutiny mentioned above. It just means that there is at least one edge in $F$ that has both its endpoints in $W$. It doesn't exclude edges whose endpoints are not in $W$, and it doesn't force all edges with endpoints in $W$ to be included. *Both* of these things are contained in the statement using "if and only if".

Comment: why can't they say: `F is a subset of E, and all its members have their endpoints in W`?  That seems clearer to me.  I could not deduce that all edges in F are under scrutiny from Definition 8.

Comment: @J.Doe Writing the formula definition as I gave, would have cleared up any of your linguistic confusion.. It was quite clear to me in words too, but we have notation for a reason..

Comment: @J.Doe Your formulation is just the definition of a subgraph. It doesn't _require_ an edge to be in $F$ if both its end points are in $W$. But we want that requirement for our definition of induced subgraph.

Comment: @Arthur, how about `W is a subset of V, and all edges they form are in F`?

Comment: @J.Doe That formulation doesn't stop $F$ from having extra edges in addition to the ones formed by $W$. If you would say something like "$F$ is the subset of $E$ consisting of all edges formed by the vertices in $W$", then you're getting there. But I really don't think the if and only if formulation is worse than that. Maybe I'm just more used to reading such formulations, though.

Comment: @Arthur, I like your straightforward wording.  The original definition suggests singularity, not totality.

Answer (score 0):

You throw away vertices and reduce $V$ to $W$ and then you simultaneously reduce $E$, the original edge set to $F$ by taking *all* edges from $E$ that have both end points in $W$. So an edge with one end or more end points in $V\setminus W$ is thrown away and is not allowed in $F$, and all others *are* in $F$ (we cannot leave it out if both ends are in $W$).

In a formula: $F=\{(v,w) \in E: v \in W \land w \in W\}$

and as it is the defining property for being in the reduced edge set $F$ we can use "if and only if".

Consider extreme cases: if $W=V$, then $F=E$ and if $W=\{v\}$ then $F=\emptyset$ unless a loop at $v$ was present (and is then also in $F$) etc.

Comment: Thanks!  The wording `an edge in E` does not seem to say all edges in $F$ to me.

Comment: @J.Doe "contains an edge in $E$" is to restrict the possible edges in $F$ to those that were in $E$ to begin with.